# Neo4j batchInserter exception

Tags: neo4j, batch-insert

I have a `Batch Inserter` that build a data model in `Neo4j`, but I have an error on creating `relationship` between nodes, not all `relationships` but some of them.

Here's the exception:

```
org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.InvalidRecordException: RelationshipRecord[someID] not in use
```

and it's thrown in that line:

```
long relId = inserter.createRelationship(node1ID, node2ID,RelTypes.My_REL,node1TOnode2RelProps);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated..

---

Here's the stacktrace

```
org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.InvalidRecordException: RelationshipRecord[454889] not in use
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.RelationshipStore.getRecord(RelationshipStore.java:254)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.RelationshipStore.getRecord(RelationshipStore.java:87)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.batchinsert.BatchInserterImpl.connect(BatchInserterImpl.java:783)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.batchinsert.BatchInserterImpl.connectRelationship(BatchInserterImpl.java:773)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.batchinsert.BatchInserterImpl.createRelationship(BatchInserterImpl.java:758)
at com.arrow.cloud.rec.bl.threads.PassRelationCall.buildPassRelation(PassRelationCall.java:395)
at com.arrow.cloud.rec.bl.threads.PassRelationCall.call(PassRelationCall.java:51)
at com.arrow.cloud.rec.bl.threads.PassRelationCall.call(PassRelationCall.java:1)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: 1) Which Neo4j version? 2) Do you start with an empty database or are you amending stuff to an existing db?

Comment: I'm using latest version 2.0.0-M03, it's an empty DB and start creating the nodes then create the relationships..

Comment: if it persists with 2.0.0-M04 report full stacktrace

Comment: What was the result of this? Did you ever solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using multiple threads in your batch insertion? If so then things are going to break. I spotted a ThreadPoolExecutor in the stack trace so that's why I ask.

Comment: I'm already using threads in this case, to make it faster as I can... Can it cause this exception ?

Comment: It's a common misconception that more threads makes things faster. Please use only one thread. I think that is what is causing your problems.